# Mysql Query Syntax Problems

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Can someone tell me what is wrong on my sql query sintax?

Also is there any way on mysql to get the exact error of the query?

```
    <?php
// If the constant _JEXEC is not defined, quit now.
// This stops this script from running outside of the system.
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function proceed()
{
check = document.getElementById('checkToProceed');
proceedButton = document.getElementById('proceedButton');

if (check.checked)
{
proceedButton.disabled = false;
}
else
{
proceedButton.disabled = true;
}
}
</script>

<?php


if ($_POST['proceedButton'] != '') { 
$user = JFactory::getUser(); 
$id = $user->get('id'); 
$name = $user->get('name');
$username = $user->get('username'); 
$department = $user->get('department'); 
$vardate = date("m/d/y : H:i:s", time()); 
$acknowledge = 1;
$courseTitle = $mainframe->getPageTitle(); 


/***************************************/

$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "INSERT INTO `jos_jquarks_users_acknowledge`(course_name)VALUES('hello')";
$db->setQuery($query);

$db->query();

echo mysql_error ();


if($db->getErrorNum()) { 
   JError::raiseError( 500, $db->stderr()); 
} 

}
?>
<form name="quiz_info" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<input type="checkbox" id="checkToProceed" name="checkToProceed" onclick="proceed();" />

<label for="checkToProceed">

<?php echo JText::_('I have Read and Acknowledge the procedure'); ?>

</label>

<input id="proceedButton" name="proceedButton" disabled="true" value="Acknowledge" type="submit" />

<input type="hidden" name="layout" value="default" /> <?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you have a field name `timestamp` ? Change that name or use bacticks around it.

Comment: i want to insert the actual time where the insertion was performed. Is that the right way of declaring a variable to get this?

Comment: That's fine, yes. The concern was over the name of the field, `timestamp` - he is concerned that it may be a reserved word. In fact, it is not: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be a couple of things, but there's a spelling error with "acknowledge".  It's spelled incorrectly in the column list of the inserts, as well as the variable you use inside the `INSERT` statement.  It's spelled correctly when you assign that variable.

Edit: Worked through this in chat with OP.  The problem was that this code was being used as a snippet inside a Joomla article.  The form's post had to go to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to post back to the proper place.

Comment: It's possible, but was worth pointing out.  Regardless, the variable name is spelled correctly when set, but not when used.

Comment: I changed and checked both the variables and the table columns and they are now allo spelled correctly, but that did not solved the issue, I added if($Db->getErrorNum()) {    JError::raiseError( 500, $Db->stderr()); }  but the page seems to be redirecting before displaing the erro

Comment: Are you sure an error is even being generated?  Have you verified that the value of `proceedButton` is not empty?  If it is, then none of this database code is being hit.

Comment: I just updated the full code, I erased every value and trying to insert a simple string to test.. but nothing gets inserted, meabe I am missing something

Comment: That leads me to believe your `if` statement is failing.  Instead of checking for the value of `proceedButton`, I'd look for the value of `checkToProceed`.  Your JS forces this to be checked before you can continue anyway.

Comment: @MattMcHugh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3011/discussion-between-tonyr-and-matt-mchugh)

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_error` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)) will return the last error from the database.

It looks like your code will execute the query twice, by the way. Only one call to `$db->query()` should be used.

As far as what, if anything is wrong, that's difficult to say. I do not see any apparent errors, but I do wonder about escaping the values you're using in the query. See the docs for [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) - if any of those values contain an apostrophe, your query would be broken.

I also see a spelling error, "acknoledge" is spelled "acknowledge", so if the field is spelled correctly in the database, then there will be a problem with the misspelling in the query. On that same note, some of your fields use `underscores_names` where some use `camelCase` names. You're just **begging** for a typo like this. Use one naming convention or the other, and keep it consistent. If your field is named `employeeNumber` and you use `employee_number` or `EmployeeNumber`, the query will fail. Pick a naming convention and stick to it so you aren't guessing every time you write a query!

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_error() or mysql_error().

Answer (score 1):

use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: Immediately after the query executes, under the line `$db->query()`. Also, as I note in my answer, you are executing the query twice in your code...

Answer (score -1):

Without the error and table structure is a bit hard but...

Maybe you're trying to insert an int datatype as a string, for example user_id. Remove the '' when using numeric values, because they are not strings.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
(id_field, string_field)
VALUES
({$id_value}, '{$string_value}');
```

Comment: -1 - Quotes around numeric fields, while possibly not sensible, will not cause an error.

Comment: I think I can troubleshoot by using this:                          `if($Db->getErrorNum()) {    JError::raiseError( 500, $Db->stderr()); } `

Comment: But no error is raised , unless is posting to another page, I get redirected to site main page , meabe thats why i dont see error?